# Many-to-Many self-referencing select sql query

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a simple table (MySQL) set up for relationships between two users.

```
 [User1Id] [User2Id]
  10        15
  14        10
  10        13
```

But, I can't figure out how to do a SELECT in such a way that I can grab the opposite UserId of the user being requested. So, if I wanted to get all relations for the user with an ID of 10, it would grab the user IDs 15, 14, and 13, and ideally join the users table with those IDs to get those users usernames. My current try is less than ideal:

```
 SELECT u1.username AS U1Username, 
        u2.username AS U2Username, 
        u1.userId AS U1UserId, 
        u2.userId AS U2UserId 
 FROM buddies b 
 LEFT JOIN users u1 on u1.userId=b.user2Id 
 LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.userId=b.user1Id 
 WHERE b.user1Id=:1 OR b.user2Id=:1
```

Then that gets filtered and rearranged in code. Is there a way that I could do one SQL query to grab everything that I need?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but just a tip from someone who implemented something similar that will save you trouble later. Add a constraint so that User1ID<User2ID. That will prevent you from getting the same relationship in the table twice (with one inverted). It also prevents someone from being related to themselves.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but it felt kind of hacky at the time. Makes sense, thinking about it.

Comment: a nice theoretical idea, although in practise, depending on your INSERT process (maybe all coders can write SQL statements, maybe theres a class/module that more closely controls inserts and can validate data) its not always safe. because people end up relying heavily on a fine detail of data integrity, which is dependant on other code. i.e. if you forget to check that in one place (a small error), you can miss out on critical information and its a hard to find bug...

Comment: @davin I was talking about a DB constraint, not one implemented in the business tier. That way you don't get people "inserting" around the constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT u.userid,
       u.username
  FROM USERS u
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM BUDDIES b
               WHERE u.userid = b.user1id
                 AND b.user2id = 10)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM BUDDIES b
               WHERE u.userid = b.user2id
                 AND b.user1id = 10)
```

...or:

```
SELECT a.user1id,
       u.username
  FROM BUDDIES a
  JOIN USERS u ON u.userid = a.user1id
 WHERE a.user2id = 10
UNION 
SELECT b.user2id,
       u.username
  FROM BUDDIES b
  JOIN USERS u ON u.userid = b.user2id
 WHERE b.user1id = 10
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates; `UNION ALL` will **not** remove duplicates and be faster for it.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about union all. Out of curiosity, is there any way to do it without making two SELECTs?

Comment: @Snea: See update.  The UNION is better if you see the criteria really changing -- the single query is saving a table scan in comparison, but the OR will likely eat that performance benefit.

Comment: @Shea - This is a single query, not two (despite the word SELECT appearing twice). There is no reason to do it without the select keyword twice. It's just a syntax thing, go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to be better optimized with, but I think this might work:

```
SELECT username, userId FROM users 
WHERE 
    userId IN (SELECT user1Id FROM buddies WHERE user2Id={ID})
  OR
    userId IN (SELECT user2Id FROM buddies WHERE user1Id={ID})
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
SELECT users.userId, users.username FROM users WHERE userId IN (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN user2id = 10 THEN user1id
        WHEN user1id = 10 THEN user2id
    END AS id 
    FROM buddies WHERE (
        (buddies.User1Id = 10 AND buddies.User2Id != 10) OR 
        (buddies.User2Id = 10 AND buddies.user1Id != 10)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The union is the easiest solution to read, but because you asked for a non-union answer. It will probably be slower than UNION ALL, because of all the CASEs, and if you have someone that is Buddy with themselves, you will get two records.

```
 SELECT 
    Case When u1.userid = :1 Then u1.username Else u2.username End AS LookForUser, 
    Case When u1.userid = :1 Then u2.username Else u1.username End AS BuddyName, 
    Case When u1.userid = :1 Then u1.userid Else u2.userid End AS LookForUserID, 
    Case When u1.userid = :1 Then u2.userid Else u1.userid End AS BuddyID, 
 FROM buddies b 
 LEFT JOIN users u1 on u1.userId=b.user2Id 
 LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.userId=b.user1Id 
 WHERE b.user1Id=:1 OR b.user2Id=:1
```